Simulate a survival dataset with specific events and HR for multiple variables
In my teaching class, students need to read and comment on a scientific article.
The next lesson is a coding lesson, and I would like them to recreate a plot from this article, so that they understand what is at stake.
Here is the source dataset, the plot (a commented forest plot) is irrelevant:
tibble::tibble(
  category = rep(c("Marker 1", "Marker 2"), each = 2L),
  level = rep(c("Yes", "No"), 2),
  gpA_n_events = c(149, 60, 119, 92),
  gpA_n_patients = c(233, 98, 192, 139),
  gpB_n_events = c(74, 35, 66, 43),
  gpB_n_patients = c(115, 47, 96, 67),
  hr_pfs__estimate = c(0.55, 0.51, 0.48, 0.54),
  hr_pfs__ci_inf = c(0.42, 0.33, 0.35, 0.37),
  hr_pfs__ci_sup = c(0.73, 0.79, 0.65, 0.73),
  gpA_pfs__median = c(10, 11.7, 10.3, 10.8),
  gpA_pfs__ci_inf = c(8.3, 9.5, 8.6, 8.4),
  gpA_pfs__ci_sup = c(11.4, 17.7, 12.3, 13.7),
  gpB_pfs__median = c(5.4, 5.9, 5.3, 5.3),
  gpB_pfs__ci_inf = c(4, 3.4, 4.1, 3.4),
  gpB_pfs__ci_sup = c(7.8, 8.2, 7.8, 7.2),
)


Here, multiple markers (I have 8 categories) have different numbers of events for each level and different Hazard ratios (calculated from a Cox model).
I would like to generate a dataset that would yield the same results as the table: 331  patients in group A and 163 patients in group B, survival times to get the specified HR (gpA vs gpB). The number of events and medians with CI are less important (but would be nice to have if easy).
I saw several great answers on that topic (e.g. here, here, and here), but the purpose was different (not the same N, only one model...).
Is what I'm trying to do possible? If yes, what would be the appropriate method?
